# Stacking datasets by creating new variables

Tags: r, dataset

I have two datasets that need to be stacked on top of each-other. Think of them as two subsets of one data-set. The issue is that they have completely different variables other than the "record_id" and one more variable

```
ds_app <- data.frame(record_id, a, b, c, d, e, f)
ds_vo  <- data.frame(record_id, g, h, i, j, k, l , m, n, o, p, q)
```

Is there an easy way to stack these other than having to create dummy variables that don't exist in the other datasets; variables with assigned NA values.

Thanks so much!

Comment: `dplyr::bind_rows(ds_app, ds_vo)`

Comment: I thought I needed to create new variables to stack them. I am aware of ```bind_rows```. Thank you! :)